# php convert .html file charset from windows-1256 to utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, file-get-contents, iconv

There are about 100,000 html files that are in windows-1256 charset and I need to convert them to utf-8 using file functions of php.

this is my code to convert one of them:

```
<?php 
    $content = file_get_contents('files/01.htm');
    $content = iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', $content);
    file_put_contents('files/01.htm', $content);
?>
```

after executing this code and visiting the `01.htm` the charachters were unformatted so I edited the `01.htm` and replaced

```
<META content="text/html ;charset=windows-1256" http-equiv=content-Type >
```

with

```
<META content="text/html ;charset=utf-8" http-equiv=content-Type>
```

But the characters are not utf-8, they are still unformatted. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: try adding setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar_AE.utf8'); before iconvert